# Como fazer uma requisição de DELETE usando o fetch?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express.js

Olá,

Estou tentando realizar uma requisição de DELETE na minha API, usando o fetch, mas estou tendo um problema com a url esperada pela API.

O método DELETE da API é o seguinte:

```
static async deletaContato(req, res) {
    const { id } = req.params;
    try {
        await database.Contatos.destroy({
            where: {
                id: Number(id)
            }
        })
        return res.status(200).json({ mensagem: `id: ${id} deletado` })
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json(error.message);
    }
}
```

A rota utilizada é a seguinte:

```
router.delete('/contatos/:id', ContatoController.deletaContato);
```

E minha função de requisição é a seguinte:

```
async function deletaContato() {
let url = 'http://localhost:3000/contatos'
const retorno = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
}).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        alert("Usuário deletado");

    });
console.log(retorno)
```

}

A minha rota espera uma url com `/contatos/:id` no final, mas não sei como fazer minha função pegar este `id` dinamicamente. Ao utilizar o postman para testar as rotas, funciona corretamente, entretanto lá eu coloco o `id` manualmente.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Na parte onde está settando sua url na função que faz a requisição, poderia talvez, passar por interpolar o id recuperado de alguma forma similar a esta...

```
let id = document.getElementById("#id-seletor-do-id");
let url = `http://localhost:3000/contatos/${id}`;
```

Comment: Só fique atento, pois as aspas são as invertidas, a famosa crase.